# Getting the last day of a given month failing at months of 31 days

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have a problem like this. For a given date I need to get the last day of each of the previous months up to 5 months. 
As an example, if the input date is 2018-08-21, then the result I want is something like (2018-07-31,2018-06-30,2018-05-31,2018-04-30,2018-03-31)

I wrote a for loop to iterate for 5 times and used the following code to get the previous month. But at months of 31 days, it doesn't exactly give the previous month. It gives the last day as "2011-07-31" which is not true. Is there a workaround for this one??

```
$datetocheck = "2011-07-31";
$lastday = date('Y-m-t', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($datetocheck)));
echo $lastday; //this gives 2011-07-31(Expected value is 2011-06-30)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and easy to understand. Try this :-

```
$initialDate = "2011-07-31";
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of -' . $i . ' month', strtotime($initialDate))) . "<br>";
}
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/pCV7U) link

Comment: @YasiruNilan Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
echo date('2011-07-31', strtotime('last day of previous month'));
//2011-06-30
```

or

```
<?php
$date = '2011-07-31';
$date = new DateTime($date);
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $date->modify("last day of previous month");
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d")."<br>";
    $newDate= $date->format("Y-m-d");
    $date=new DateTime($newDate);
}
?>
```

Comment: This works for one time only I think. How to get it for multiple previous months?

Comment: I ran it for 5 times using for loop, everytime it is giving the same date as output.    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$date = new DateTime('2011-07-31');
$date->modify("last day of previous month");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
  echo "n";
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DateTime` Classe. You can run this in a loop like following

```
function lastDayOfMonth($datetocheck, $noOfMonth){

    $date = new \DateTime($datetocheck);
    $month = ((int) ($date)->format('m'))-$noOfMonth;
    $year = ($date)->format('Y');

    $lastMonth = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}");

    $lastday = $lastMonth->format('Y-m-t');

    echo $lastday . PHP_EOL;

}

for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++){
    lastDayOfMonth('2011-07-31', $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For solve that problem you can try this

```
<?php
$datetocheck = "2011-07-31";
$tmp_date = date('Y-m-01',strtotime($datetocheck));
$lastday = date('Y-m-t', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime($tmp_date)));
echo $lastday; //this value is 2011-06-30
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

requirement could be achieved by using loop with use of DateTime. If am right in understating please try

```
$startDate = new DateTime('2018-08-21');

$dateArr = array();

for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
  $date = $startDate;

  $date->modify("last day of previous month");
  $lastDateOfMonth =  $date->format("Y-m-d");

  $dateArr[] = $lastDateOfMonth;
  $startDate = new DateTime($lastDateOfMonth);
}

$dateList = implode(",", $dateArr);

echo $dateList;
```

Comment: Glad to help you